# Decomposition and Inertia groups and Frobenius automorphism computations

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{-1}]$. Calculate the Frobenius automorphisms $\left(\frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)$ for $p$ prime distinct from $2$ and $5$ (which are the only primes that ramify in $K$). Calculate the decomposition and inertia groups for $2$ and $5$.

This is related to an exercise in Milne; it would help me a lot to understand better the concepts if someone is willing to do this particular case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll tackle the Frobenius elements first.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{5})$. We have $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})=\{\operatorname{id}_K,\rho,\tau,\rho\tau\}\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where $\rho$ is complex conjugation and $\tau$ is the automorphism of $K$ switching $\sqrt{5}$ and $-\sqrt{5}$.

---

**Fact 1:** Given

- an extension of number fields $E/F$
- a prime $P\subset\mathcal{O}_F$ that doesn't ramify in $E$
- any prime $\mathcal{P}\subset\mathcal{O}_E$ above $P$

then for any intermediate field $L$ such that $L/F$ is Galois, letting $\mathbf{P}=\mathcal{P}\cap\mathcal{O}_L$ the prime of $L$ lying beneath $\mathcal{P}$, we have 
$$(\mathcal{P},E/F)|_L=(\mathbf{P},L/F).$$

**Fact 2:** For a squarefree integer $D$, the field $M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ has discriminant $d_M=4D$ if $D\equiv 2,3\bmod 4$ and $d_M=D$ if $D\equiv 1\bmod 4$, and if $p\nmid d_M$ is an odd prime, 
$$p\text{ splits if }\left(\frac{D}{p}\right)=1\qquad\text{and}\qquad p\text{ is inert if }\left(\frac{D}{p}\right)=-1,$$
(these being Legendre symbols).

I can include proofs of these facts if you would like.

---

Let $p$ be a prime of $\mathbb{Q}$ that doesn't ramify in $K$, i.e. $p\neq 2,5$. By Fact 1, $$\textstyle\left.\left(\frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)\right|_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}=\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)\in\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q})\quad\text{and}\quad\left.\left(\frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)\right|_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}=\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)\in\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q})$$
Thus, computing $\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)$ will allow us to find $\left(\frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)$, because an element of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is determined by what it does to $\sqrt{5}$ and $i$. Let $\mathfrak{P}\subset\cal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}$ and $\mathfrak{p}\subset\cal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}$ be any primes lying over $p$.

---

There are two elements of $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q})$, $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}$ and $\tau$, where $\tau(\sqrt{5})=-\sqrt{5}$. Note that $\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}$ if and only if $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}$ induces the Frobenius automorphism on $(\cal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}/\mathfrak{P})/(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, i.e. every element of $\cal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}/\mathfrak{P}$ is its own $p$th power, which is the case if and only if $\cal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}/\mathfrak{P}\cong\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e. $f(\mathfrak{P}/p)=1$. Recall that $p$ does not ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ by assumption, so that $e(\mathfrak{P}/p)=1$. Because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois of prime degree, $e(\mathfrak{P}/p)=1$ and $f(\mathfrak{P}/p)=1$ if and only if $p$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Thus, we have shown that $\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}$ if and only if $p$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, which Fact 2 tells us happens if and only if $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=1$. By quadratic reciprocity, this is the case if and only if $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=1$, i.e. $p\equiv1,4\bmod 5$. Thus
$$\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)=\begin{cases}\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}\quad\text{ if }p\equiv1,4\bmod 5\\
\,\,\,\tau\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\text{ if }p\equiv 2,3\bmod 5\end{cases}$$

A similar analysis with $\frak{p}$ shows that
$$\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)=\begin{cases}\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}\quad\text{ if }p\equiv1\bmod 4\\
\,\,\,\rho\quad\quad\quad\;\text{ if }p\equiv 3\bmod 4\end{cases}$$

Because

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 & p\equiv1\bmod4 & p\equiv 3\bmod 4 \\\hline
p\equiv 1,4\bmod 5 & p\equiv 1,9\bmod 20 & p\equiv11,19\bmod 20\\\hline
p\equiv 2,3\bmod 5 & p\equiv 17,13\bmod 20 & p\equiv 7,3\bmod 20\\\hline
\end{array}$$
we have that
$$\left(\frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)=\begin{cases}\operatorname{id}_K\quad\text{ if } p\equiv 1,9\bmod 20\\ \tau\quad\quad\;\;\text{ if } p\equiv 13,17\bmod20 \\ \rho\quad\quad\;\;\text{ if } p\equiv 11,19\bmod 20\\ \rho\tau\quad\quad\text{ if }p \equiv 3,7\bmod 20\end{cases}$$

---

Now to find the decomposition and inertia groups for $2$ and $5$. We will need

**Fact 3:** Given

- an **abelian** Galois extension of number fields $L/F$
- a prime $P\subset\mathcal{O}_F$
- a prime $\mathcal{P}\subset\mathcal{O}_L$ lying over $P$

then

- the inertia field of $\mathcal{P}$ over $P$, i.e. the fixed field of $I(\mathcal{P}/P)$, is the largest intermediate field in which $P$ does not ramify
- the decomposition field of $\mathcal{P}$ over $P$, i.e. the fixed field of $D(\mathcal{P}/P)$, is the largest intermediate field in which $P$ splits completely.

The intermediate fields of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ are, of course,
$$K$$
$$\text{ / }\qquad |\qquad \text{ \ }$$
$$\quad\quad\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})\quad\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5})\,\,\,\,\quad \mathbb{Q}(i)\quad\quad$$
$$\text{ \ } \qquad |\qquad \text{ / }$$
$$\mathbb{Q}$$
which have discriminants
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
& & 400 & & \\
& & & & \\
5 & & -20 & & -4\\
& & & & \\
& & 1 & & 
\end{array}$$
(sorry about the ugly diagram, the LaTeX on the site has some limitations)

Because a prime ramifies if and only if it divides the discriminant, we see that the inertia field of $2$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, and the inertia field of $5$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Thus, $I(\mathcal{P}/2)=\{\operatorname{id}_K,\rho\}$ for any prime $\mathcal{P}\subset\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $2$, and $I(\mathfrak{P}/5)=\{\operatorname{id}_K,\tau\}$ for any prime $\mathfrak{P}\subset\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $5$.

Because the decomposition group contains the inertia group, the inertia field contains the decomposition field. Thus, the decomposition field for $2$ is either $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, and the decomposition field for $5$ is either $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ or $\mathbb{Q}$. By Fact 2, $2$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $5$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$  (indeed $5=(2+i)(2-i)$), so the decomposition field for $2$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ and the decomposition field for $5$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Thus, $D(\mathcal{P}/2)=\{\operatorname{id}_K,\rho,\tau,\rho\tau\}=\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ for any prime $\mathcal{P}\subset\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $2$, and $D(\mathfrak{P}/5)=\{\operatorname{id}_K,\tau\}$ for any prime $\mathfrak{P}\subset\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $5$.

Comment: This is a really nice answer, Zev.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words :)

Comment: It really is. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @ZevChonoles, this is really a wonderful answer

Answer (score 3):

Instead of thinking in terms of decomposition group and inertia group, sometimes it's easier to think in terms of the corresponding fields (via the usual Galois correspondence).  For *abelian* Galois groups (as is the case for $K$ here), it's particularly simple:

The decomposition group corresponds to the largest subextension of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ over which $p$ splits completely.  (This subextension is usually called the decomposition field.)

The inertia group corresponds to the largest subextension of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ over which $p$ is unramified.  (This subextension is usually called the inertia field.)

(Note: In the non-abelian case, it's a little more complicated.  The decomposition and inertia groups are only determined up to conjugacy by the lower prime $p$; to get a specific subgroup, we need to choose a prime $P$ in $K$ lying above $p$.  In the above statements, we would need to change "largest subextension" to "largest subextension such that $P$ lies over the subextension".)

Now we can tackle $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{-1})$.  Consider first the case $p \ne 2,5$.  Note that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ has 3 proper subextensions: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.  Check that $p$ either splits in all 3 of these subextensions, in which case the decomposition field is all of $K$ (so the decomposition group is trivial), or else $p$ splits in exactly one of the subextensions, in which case the decomposition field is that subextension (the decomposition group is the corresponding subgroup of order 2).  The Frobenius automorphism is a generator of the decomposition group, which is uniquely determined in these cases since the decomposition groups all have order 1 or 2.

I'll leave the ramified cases $p=2,5$ to you for now.